# How to send a array of object to restful WCF with POST and JSON

Tags: json, wcf, rest

when i'm trying to send json with POST method, i'm getting error

```
[{"ExtensionData":null,"Date":"12/16/2014 22:11:16","IsPlayer":false,"MagicInfo":null,"SpellInfo":null},{"ExtensionData":null,"Date":"12/16/2014 22:11:16","IsPlayer":false,"MagicInfo":null,"SpellInfo":null}]
```

service:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "InsertCastActivities", Method = "POST",
                    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[OperationContract]
bool InsertCastActivities(List<CastActivityDto> castActivitiesDto);
```

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Request Error
>   The server encountered an error processing the request. See server
>   logs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What is definition of class CastActivityDto? 
You must define a DataContract and Datamember attribute.

so class must be something like this

```
[DataContract]
public class CastActivityDto
{
   [DataMember]
   public string SomeAttribute { get;set;}

   [DataMember]
   public string AnotherAttribute { get;set;}
}
```

then you can post JSON data in format

```
{
  castActivitiesDto :
  [
     {SomeAttribute : "1", AnotherAttribute : "1" },
     {SomeAttribute : "2", AnotherAttribute : "2" }
  ]   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a DATETIME type error.

When it is:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual String Time
{
    get { return this.date.ToString(); }
    set
    {
        this.date = value != null ? DateTime.Parse(value) : DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

everything works fine ! :)